# SQL help for Group by clause on one field and specific record count condition on another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot, having-clause

Need help getting a SQL. I have below kind of table.

[image: -----]

Need below result records based on the fact that they  have "abc" and "def" in Field2

- just one occurrence of each value not more
- no other value apart from "abc" and "def".

Expected result

[image: ---]

Records that should not be in result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMefY.png)

I have tried different experiments with

```
Select * from MYTABLE
WHERE FIELD1 in ('abc','def')
Group by Field1
Having Count(*) = 2
```

but am doing something fundamentally wrong here, as it gives me "Member4" also since it has two occurrences of "abc"

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregate expressions in the `having` clause:

```
select field1
from mytable
group by field1
having
        sum(case when field2 = 'abc' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and sum(case when field2 = 'def' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and sum(case when field2 not in ('abc', 'def') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support string aggregation.  That can be the simplest method.  For instance, in MySQL syntax:

```
select field1
from t
group by field1
having group_concat(field2 order by field2) = 'abc,def';
```